Tailwindcss default styles applied but utility classes are not working
I'm trying to set Tailwindcss up in a Vite project. I have two directories storybook and components. I write my code in components and preview them in storybook. As a test I'm trying to apply the class text-3xl to an example component which has no effect.
Here is my tailwind.config.js file:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["{src,pages,components,app,storybook}/**/*!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,tsx,html}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


My postcss.config.cjs file:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}


I've tried setting content to an absolute path and it's still not working.

I would first double check that tailwind is installed properly. I would check the HTML when you apply the test-3xl class to see if it's at least listed in your component when rendered. If it is, then this could be an issue with your Storybook configuration and dependencies, there is a similar question that was answered here that might help Storybook errors when adding tailwindcss
